# Reducing execution time of a piece of code in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab

I have the following piece of code in Matlab

```
    n=15
    eqtocheck=randn(196584,17);
    tic 
    others=zeros(size(eqtocheck,1),n-1); 
    for i=1:n-1
        behavothers=eqtocheck(:,3:end);
        behavothers(:,i)=[];
        others(:,i)=sum(behavothers,2); 
                   %for each kth row of eqtocheck, 
                   %sum all elements of the row except the ith element 
                   %and report the sum in the (k,i) element of others
    end
    toc
```

It takes me around 0.25 sec to run it with Matlab-r2015a. Could you suggest a way to reduce execution time (I cannot use parfor because it is applied to an external loop)?

Comment: What is a typical value for `n`?

Comment: Question edited, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) it -

```
A = eqtocheck(:,3:end);
others = bsxfun(@minus,sum(A,2),A(:,1:end-1));
```

---

**Benchmarking**

Benchmarking code -

```
n=15;
eqtocheck=randn(196584,17);

disp('---------------- Before BSXFUNing -------------')
tic
others=zeros(size(eqtocheck,1),n-1);
for i=1:n-1
    behavothers=eqtocheck(:,3:end);
    behavothers(:,i)=[];
    others(:,i)=sum(behavothers,2);
end
toc

disp('---------------- After BSXFUNing -------------')
tic
A = eqtocheck(:,3:end);
others_out = bsxfun(@minus,sum(A,2),A(:,1:end-1));
toc
```

Runtimes -

```
---------------- Before BSXFUNing -------------
Elapsed time is 0.759202 seconds.
---------------- After BSXFUNing -------------
Elapsed time is 0.069710 seconds.
```

Verify results -

```
>> error_val = max(abs(others(:)-others_out(:)))
error_val =
   6.2172e-15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 n=13
eqtocheck=randn(196584,16);
tic
others=zeros(size(eqtocheck,1),16);
for i=1:n-1
    behavothers=eqtocheck(:,3:end);
    behavothers(:,i)=[];
    others(:,i)=sum(behavothers,2);
    %for each kth row of eqtocheck,
    %sum all elements of the row except the ith element
    %and report the sum in the (k,i) element of others
end
toc
% using straight math with repmat to expand the matrix
tic
values = eqtocheck(:,3:end);
tempsum = sum(values, 2);
tempsum2 = repmat(tempsum, 1, n + 1);
result = tempsum2 - values;
toc
```

Elapsed time is 0.237134 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.026789 seconds.

The values are not exactly the same but they are numerically equivalent.  The columns are not the same between others and result but you can see which ones you want.